# Unable to read the values of dynamically created text boxes .Facing undefined html error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a  row of 3 textboxes dynamically.But i am not able to read the values of the same.

Below is the code for creation of textboxes.

```
$(function() {
  $('#addVNFButton').on('click', function() {
    if (vnfCounter > 10) {
      alert("only 10 vnf's are allowed");
      return false;
    }
    //e.preventDefault();
    $('<div/>').addClass('col-md-12')

      .html('<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><label class="control-label">Vendor</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vnfVendor"/></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><label class="control-label">Product Name</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vnfProductName"/></div><div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><label class="control-label">Release</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vnfRelease"/></div>')
      .append($('<button/>').addClass('btn btn-action remove').text('Delete'))
      .insertAfter($('#vnfSection'));
    vnfCounter++;
  });
});
```

above code creates 3 textboxes in a row like below.

[image]

Below is the code which i tried to read values.

```
for (var i = 1; i < vnfCounter; i++) {
  var vnfVendor = "";
  var vnfProduct = "";
  var vnfRelease = "";
  vnfVendor += $('#vnfVendor' + i).val();

  vnfProduct += $('#vnfProductName' + i).val();
  vnfRelease] += $('#vnfRelease' + i).val();
}
```

I am getting the result as undefined html object.Pls help

Comment: Without seeing a working example of the problem we can only guess. But i believe the problem is that reset `vnfVendor` and others in the loop, so every time you loop then you select the values in it.

Comment: I don't see any elements with id `vnfVendor[n]` - only one with hard-coded `vnfVendor`. Maybe that's where the issue lies.

Comment: Also note that you are not assigning a new id to the new objects, so you get duplicated ID, and that is a big no no.

Comment: So should i use UUID?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a closing div tag `<div/>` instead of opening div tag `<div>`.

```
$('<div>').addClass('col-md-12')
```

Hope it will help you. Happy coding...!

Answer (score 0):

Add **Name** attr. to your dynamically created textbox

```
 var Titles = $("input[name='TitleField']").map(function () { return $(this).val().trim(); }).get();
```

above code will return all the textbox vlaue in array. 
This is working for me